# Filter Objects returned by Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, windows-7, powershell-2.0

I had a look at the properties available for objects returned by Get-ChildItem command using:

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem | Get-Member
```

This command shows that objects returned by Get-ChildItem command possess properties 'Name, FullName, LastAccessTime etc...'

I declare a variable to retrieve objects starting with 'Program':

```
PS C:\> $ChildItems_Program = Get-ChildItem -name 'Program*'
```

Checking what is stored in $ChildItems_Program

```
PS C:\> $ChildItems_Program
Program Files
Program Files (x86)
```

Trying to access properties 'Name, FullName, LastAccessTime' from the first object saved in $ChildItems_Program

```
PS C:\> $ChildItems_Program[0] | Select -Property Name, FullName, LastAccessTime

Name                                 FullName                             LastAccessTime
----                                 --------                             --------------
```

Why I can't see any results for above command- Shouldn't it return the properties of first object saved in $ChildItems_Program?
Can anyone please guide.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) ( equivalent to `get-help get-childitem` )

```
-Name
Gets only the names of the items in the locations. If you pipe the output of this command to another command, only the item names are sent.
```

Comment: Yes CB, I found out that command: Get-ChildItem -name 'Program*' return a string[], to actually return the object, I should use the switch: -Filter instead of -Name.